# Why do I get an error when I try to model autocorrelation, even when exactly following this example in Pinheiro and Bates (2009)?

Tags: r

**Here is an excerpt from [Mixed Effects Models in S and S-Plus](http://books.google.com/books?id=y54QDUTmvDcC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) page [238](http://books.google.com/books?id=y54QDUTmvDcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=pinheiro+bates&hl=en&ei=I6LRTauWDIXagQeq4byxDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=corSpher&f=false):**

---

[image]
[image]

---

**this is the code that I have used to recreate this example:**

```
library(nlme)
spatDat <- data.frame(x = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), y = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.50,0.75))
cs1Exp <- corExp(1, form = ~x+y)
cs1Exp <- initialize(cs1Exp, spatDat)
```

**but when I do so, I get this error:**

```
Error in getClass(Class) : 
  c("\"corExp\" is not a defined class", "\"corSpatial\" is not a defined class", "\"corStruct\" is not a defined class")
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!is.na(match(Class, .BasicClasses))) return(newBasic(Class,  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

**Why do I get this error?**

---

*Appendix*

```
R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] nlme_3.1-101

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.13.0     lattice_0.19-26
```

Comment: Well, isn't your data for y wrong in the line: spatDat <- data.frame(x = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), y = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.50,0.75))

Comment: You have 0.5 for observations 3 and 4 when it should be only for observation 3, then from there you get the observation 5 also wrong....

Comment: This should probably be moved to crossvalidated.com

Comment: @Brandon: despite the title, this question is really about coding more than about statistics.

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that the book claims to be about S and S-PLUS, *not* R. It is not surprising that code in the book doesn't work in it's entirety within R, which only claims to be an implementation of the S language and "not unlike" S-PLUS (whatever that means). Reading the help for `?corExp` would have shown the change needed to `Initialize()`.

Comment: @Vivi my d.f. did have a typo, but this was not the cause of the error

Comment: @Gavin thanks for pointing out that this exact example is provided with correct syntax for R in the `corExp` documentation.

Comment: @David I realise that, and that's the reason it was a comment rather than an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that [`Initialize`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/nlme/html/Initialize.html) takes a capital `I` in `nlme` so it is not confused with `initialize` in `base`. And then there is Vivi's comment on `spatdat$y`

This works:

```
> library(nlme)
> spatDat <- data.frame(x = c(0,0.25,0.5,0.75,1), y = c(0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1.0))
> cs1Exp <- corExp( 1, form = ~x+y )
> cs1Exp <- Initialize( cs1Exp, spatDat )
> corMatrix( cs1Exp )
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.7021885 0.4930687 0.3462272 0.2431167
[2,] 0.7021885 1.0000000 0.7021885 0.4930687 0.3462272
[3,] 0.4930687 0.7021885 1.0000000 0.7021885 0.4930687
[4,] 0.3462272 0.4930687 0.7021885 1.0000000 0.7021885
[5,] 0.2431167 0.3462272 0.4930687 0.7021885 1.0000000
```

Comment: that just wasted an hour of my life

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of problems with your code.    Here's the corrected version:

```
library(nlme)    
spatDat <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), y = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0))    
cs1Exp <- corExp(1, form = ~x+y)    
cs1Exp <- Initialize(cs1Exp, spatDat)  
corMatrix(cs1Exp)  

          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 1.0000000 0.7021885 0.4930687 0.3462272 0.2431167
[2,] 0.7021885 1.0000000 0.7021885 0.4930687 0.3462272
[3,] 0.4930687 0.7021885 1.0000000 0.7021885 0.4930687
[4,] 0.3462272 0.4930687 0.7021885 1.0000000 0.7021885
[5,] 0.2431167 0.3462272 0.4930687 0.7021885 1.0000000
```

Answer (score 3):

To emphasize the quality of the documentation (and hopefully to save someone else time when working with such a well documented textbook package), I will point out that the code in question is provided in the help file under `?corExp`

```
Examples:

     # Pinheiro and Bates, p. 238
     spatDat <- data.frame(x = (0:4)/4, y = (0:4)/4)

     cs1Exp <- corExp(1, form = ~ x + y)
     cs1Exp <- Initialize(cs1Exp, spatDat)
     corMatrix(cs1Exp)
     ...
```